# Keycloak in Docker failing to start due to an IOException

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak

I'm trying to implement token authorization using Keycloak, but I'm running into issues with the JBoss/Keycloak Docker image that I'm using for development.

When using a newly installed Docker with no containers or images aside from the JBoss/Keycloak one, a new instance of Keycloak fails to start every time:

```
 WARNING [org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) IOException occurred while connecting to postgres:5432: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

Then get a long output of other JVM errors and warnings after this first one. Obviously, it needs Postgres, but wouldn't the image already contain all the dependencies it needs?

In [this video](https://youtu.be/NZI3C6vdjQk?t=65), this person is able to run a Docker container with Keycloak flawlessly.

Here's [a link to the full log](https://pastebin.com/mv1E3r9W) (it exceeds the maximum length for a post on Stack Overflow).

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I found a docker-compose file that initializes a Postgres container and a Keycloak container.

https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-postgres.yml

This got my Keycloak instance up and running without error, but I don't fully understand why a Postgres container is necessary. The guy in that video didn't launch one, nor did I the first time I was able to setup a Keycloak instance on a different computer.

Comment: By default Keycloak uses embedded Java-based relational database called H2.  For Production external DB like  Postgres and MySql are recommended

Comment: @ravthiru: I understand. It says in the log on initialization "Using Embedded H2" or "PostgreSQL". What I don't understand is why this seems to be a hit or miss which DB it uses. When I wrote the original post, it kept wanting to use PostgreSQL by default. Today's it's using the H2 DB. I'm just trying to develop an OIDC adapter for Keycloak. it doesn't matter if this instance of Keycloak is deployed for production or not. Am I missing some DB setting when building the container?